# Compilation terminal output

Tags: command-line, external-command, terminal

When I compile and execute a c++ program in vim it outputs "command terminated" however when I compile it in geany (another ide) it outputs "segmentation fault". Is there a way to get vim to output the same message as geany?

Comment: That depends on how you compile and run it? What do you use? `:make`?

Comment: @muru No, I just typed :!g++ E9.26.cpp then ran the program with :!./a.out.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `:!./a.out`, the `Segmentation fault` message is printed [by the shell that ran the command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53385/70524), *not* the command itself. You could run something like<sup>1</sup>:

```
:!{ ./a.out; } 2>&1
```

This redirects the stderr of the shell within the command group, so the message from the shell is also captured:

```
/bin/bash: line 1:  7153 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./a.out

shell returned 139

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Or run the command in a subshell:

```
:!( ./a.out; )
```

This has similar output to the above option.

With more complex programs, you'll probably end up using some sort of build system, such as `make`. In which case, the program won't be run directly by the shell, but by the makefile, so you'll get the error message.

<sup><sup>1</sup>This depends on the shell. I'm assuming `bash`, and couldn't get the same effect from `zsh`.</sup>